# Migrating custom objects from dev org to production org

Tags: deployment, package

I created an app with some custom objects in my free dev environment, and I want most of it to get migrated to our brand new production environment.

Unfortunately there is a lot of experimental stuff in my dev environment that I would have to delete if I added the entire App to a package.

If I simply add the custom objects to the package, is there a way to re-create the app in the new environment and add the objects from the package to it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just be sure to add only the **Custom Objects** themselves and not the **Application**. The platform only automatically adds related child components when you add things to packages, for example Tab adds Custom Objects, Application adds related Tabs. So just be sure to add at the level you want to include things in and you can build a package without the Application in it.

Comment: Thanks. What about adding it to a new app on the destination side?

Comment: Once the Custom Objects are installed in the destination org, go to Setup > Create > Apps and edit the app to add your Tabs.